# iOS In-App Purchase tester dialog missing Apple ID entry field

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store, appstore-sandbox

[image]

My Sandbox dialog used to come up with an Apple ID field but after I have entered the credentials wrong several times im now suck with a version of this dialog without the Apple ID entry field. I've tried General>"Remove all data", deleting and recompiling app to device and signing into different Gooogle accounts but nothing helps

Anyone know how to get this version of the dialog back so I can try new tester accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS 12+ you may have a sandbox account set up in your device settings. Go to Settings -> Account -> iTunes & App Store -> Sandbox Account (at the bottom). You can tap that account and sign-out.

Comment: thanks will try that if I get stuck again ^.^

For now had my contractor switch to TestFlight and that seems to work